# Change GitHub credentials in PyCharm

Tags: github, pycharm

I am learning to use GitHub and so far only from PyCharm. Recently, I updated my GitHub page with a new username, email and address. I changed the credentials in PyCharm going to `Settings` `>` `Version control` `>` `Github` and running the test I do get the message successful connection. However, when I try to commit my projects I get a failed connection message as it tries to reach the old address. This is the message I get:

```
Push failed:
ProjectName: failed with error: Authentication failed for 'Old_Repositoriy_url'
```

It seems other users are experiencing a [similar error](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000325944-How-to-change-remote-git-repositories-credentials-), however, I do not know how to change my git credentials from the terminal...

I am using PyCharm 2017.2 in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to go to:

> Settings -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> Passwords.

Then change it to "Do not save, forget passwords after start".

Now when you restart your IDE the issue should be solved (you will have to re-authenticate).  If you want to save your new password just re-enable the option after a restart.

Answer (score 4):

Pycharm can also be using the Windows credentials manager.  So, if the accepted answer doesn't work and you're using Windoze, open the windows cm (type "credential manager" in the search box), select the "Windows Credentials" tab, expand the entry for your git repo, and click "Remove". You'll be prompted to re-enter the user/pwd the next time you access it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the repository address, you can do so by running the following command from the terminal (there's no UI for this in PyCharm):

```
git remote set-url origin <your new url>
```